# A word or phrase for deliberately trying to lose something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase to express when someone wants to lose his nasty cat, deliberately trying to leave it in some jungle or street? He tries to lose it in the streets so that it won't come back.

For example:
Estelle is trying to _________ her cat.

Comment: Cat-hater? Skank?

Comment: Hi Kalesh, welcome to English Language & Usage. Your question falls within the category of [tag:single-word-requests] ("SWRs"), so I've edited it to add the tag and also add a sample sentence. FYI for future questions, SWRs have a special requirement: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. You must include **a sample sentence** demonstrating how the word would be used." [My emphasis]. :-)

Comment: With 'trying to', 'lose' works.

Comment: She's trying to ***ditch*** her cat.

Comment: We call it *dumping*.

Comment: _Misplace_ has a note of delicacy about it.

Comment: Kalesh, don't forget to review the answers to your question, and give the green tick of approval if there's one that meets your needs. This is one of the privileges of asking a question! For transparency, I should note that I'm one of the five that posted an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[**Abandon**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abandon)

> verb (used with object)
>   1. to leave completely and finally; forsake utterly; desert:
>   *"to abandon one's farm; to abandon a child; to abandon a sinking ship."*

Hence:

> Estelle is trying to abandon her cat.

Answer (score 4):

*Lose* works just fine.

**Lose** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lose)

> (US, informal) *verb* 2.3  Get rid of (an undesirable person or thing)
>
> *"lose that creep!"*
> *"They need to lose that awful voiceover."*
> *"You need to lose that creep before he pressures you into more things you don't want to do."*

Synonyms: **ditch, abandon, dump**...

Comment: Lose does work; and the ambiguity (of whether the losing is intentional or not) is resolved by the description of Emily as _trying_ to lose her cat.

Answer (score 3):

I think [***abandon***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abandon) works here.

> Cease to support or look after (someone); desert:
> *her natural mother had abandoned her at an early age*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abandon

Answer (score 2):

What about to **get rid of** from [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+rid+of):

> To rid oneself of (something); discard or get free of
>
> "It's time we got rid of this trash."

Or **expel** from [FreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expel)

> To force or drive out
>
> "to expel an invader from a country".

Answer (score -2):

If you want to put emphasis of an intentional loss made to look like an accident, you could allude to a classic fairy tale, in which something or somebody is lost, making it look like an accident:

- ***pulling a Hänsel and Gretel*** – [Hänsel and Gretel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel) is a Grimm fairy tale in which Hänsel’s and Gretel’s parents abandon them in the woods, allegedly to make it look accidental to the fellow villagers. The only disadvantage is that it’s not Hänsel and Gretel who do this but their parents, so technically you would have to say *pulling a Hänsel’s and Gretel’s parents,* which I consider rather clumsy.

  > Estelle is trying to pull a Hänsel and Gretel on her cat.
- ***pulling a Cinderella*** – [Cinderella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella#Aschenputtel.2C_by_the_Brothers_Grimm) is another Grimm fairy tale, in which Cinderella losing a slipper turns to her advantage as it allows her desired spouse to find her. Therefore one could allege her of losing the slipper intentionally, although this is not explicitly mentioned in the fairy tale.

  > Estelle is trying to pull a Cinderella on her cat.

Comment: These usages seem to be invented - I have never encountered them in English before.

Comment: @VinceBowdren: I did not claim otherwise.